# Close all workbooks but active one without breaking links?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to close all the workbooks, but the active one without breaking links.

```
Sub dateUpdate()

Dim WB As Workbook
Dim TestWkbk As Workbook
Dim obj As Object
Range("C1").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Workbooks.Open Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\receiving.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True
ActiveWindow.Visible = False
Workbooks.Open Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\packing.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True
ActiveWindow.Visible = False
Workbooks.Open Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\shipping.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True
ActiveWindow.Visible = False
Workbooks.Open Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\hoist.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True
ActiveWindow.Visible = False
ThisWorkbook.Activate
'Application.ScreenUpdating = True



If Val(Application.Version) >= 12 Then
    Set TestWkbk = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set TestWkbk = Workbooks("WinDatePicker.xlam")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If TestWkbk Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Sorry the Date Picker add-in is not open."
    Else
        Application.Run "'" & TestWkbk.Name & "'!OpenDatePicker", obj
    End If
End If


For Each WB In Workbooks
If WB.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
    WB.Close savechanges:=False
End If
Next WB


End Sub
```

If I choose a new date then I will get reference errors because the books are already closed.  Any way around this?

Comment: Are you trying to find out how to close all workbooks except the current one AND the one containing the "Date Picker add-in"?  (If the "links" you are referring to are to cells in the other xlsx files, you should probably just open those files again.)

Answer (score 2):

The below code will close all workbooks except the active one

```
Dim wb As Workbook
For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
    If Not (wb Is Application.ActiveWorkbook) Then
        wb.Close
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Closing all except Active workbook

```
Sub test()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim ActiveWB: ActiveWB = ThisWorkbook.Name

    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If (wb.Name <> ActiveWB) Then
            wb.Close
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```